# Kotlin RxJava2 combine latest

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a list of observables, each one returns, lets say, a string

```
val list = listOf<Observable<String>>(
                Observable.fromCallable { "1" },
                Observable.fromCallable { "2" },
                Observable.fromCallable { "3" },
                Observable.fromCallable { "4" }
        )
```

And i would like to combine'em.

```
    val result: Observable<String> = Observable.combineLatest(
            list,
            Function<Array<String>, String> { results ->
                var resultString = ""
                //combine
                resultString
            })
```

Kotlin shows me **None of the following function can be called...** error.
I saw some posts about **SAM constructor**, but here i have specified types explicitly.
Cannot figure out how to solve.

**P.S.** Workaround is `Function<Array<in String>, String>` but then `results` gonna be `Array<Any>`, but not `Array<String>`.

Comment: Would recommend using `RxKotlin` https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin ...among other things it has number of helper methods to get around SAM ambiguity issues.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, but what if i don't want)

Comment: it's just a recommendation....you don't have to do anything you don't want to do :)

Comment: Did you try do it without type specification? val result: Observable<String> = Observable.combineLatest(list) { results -> "" }

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky yes, result is Array<out Any> in that case

Answer (score 3):

you can specify the type on the lambda parameter itself, like:

```
Observable.combineLatest(list, Function { results: Array<in String> ->
    ...
})
```

you can further condense things by removing the SAM constructor and moving the lambda out of the argument list for `combineLatest()`, like:

```
Observable.combineLatest(list) { results: Array<in String> ->
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into a sources

```
public static <T, R> Observable<R> combineLatest(Iterable<? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> sources,
        Function<? super Object[], ? extends R> combiner) {
    return combineLatest(sources, combiner, bufferSize());
}
```

Because of

```
? super Object[]
```

I think you have to use

```
Array <in String>
```

And regarding results - you can use

```
Observable.combineLatest(
            list,
            Function<Array<in String>, String> { results ->
                val resultList = results.map { it.toString() }
                //combine
                ...
                results[0]
            })
```

I haven't found other solutions